# ms access insert-sql exception : general error

Tags: java, sql, swing, ms-access

[image]

```
Jan 03, 2017 2:37:52 PM my.god.godGUI jButton2ActionPerformed     
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: General error
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6993)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecute(JdbcOdbc.java:3156)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:215)
at    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java:137)
at my.god.godGUI.jButton2ActionPerformed(godGUI.java:200)
at my.god.godGUI.access$000(godGUI.java:20)
at my.god.godGUI$1.actionPerformed(godGUI.java:63)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

here is my java file which corresponds to the error ,

**JAva file :**

```
    int price=Integer.parseInt(jTextField3.getText());
    int num=Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    int amt=price*num;
    jLabel4.setText(""+amt);


    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:yum");
        String sql="insert into Table1 values(?,?,?)";
        p=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        p.setInt(1,num);
        p.setInt(2,price);
        p.setInt(3,amt);
       p.executeUpdate();

    }
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException s){
    Logger.getLogger(godGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, s);

    }
    finally{
        try {
            p.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(godGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

when i run this file for the first tym it works but the next tym it pops up the same error always.

I have referred the previous answers to change the dsn,reacrete the file,close the connection in the finally block but still the error comes up.

Am i missing something here?

Any help with whats wrong?

Comment: Can you show the table ?

Comment: i have added an image of my table

Answer (score 0):

As you are using following syntex for insert query without column names

String sql="insert into Table1 values(?,?,?)";

you have to make sure you provide every column value in your table, even the nullable ones. And you also have to make sure that you provide them in the exact order they are defined in the database.

or use Syntax as below .
 String sql="insert into Table1 (num, price, amt) values(?,?,?)";

Please share Database Table for more clarification.

Comment: when i made the above change i got this error - 'java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'